# Scrapy Spider: Don't crawl sites that are in a list

Tags: python, scrapy

At the moment I have one rule in my scrapy spider:

```
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/item/\d+']), 'parse_item')]
```

That means that all links like *www.site.com/item/123654* get extracted and then will be parsed. The number behind */item/* is a unique id. The result of the spidering will be stored in a json-file.

Additionally, I have a csv-file with about 200,000 ids that were crawled already and I don't want these sites to get crawled again in order to reduce server load. So lets say I create a python-list of this csv like:

```
dontparse = [123111, 123222, 123333, 123444, ...]
```

Now I don't want these ids just to be ignored if these links are found during crawling, I want them to be stored in the json-file, just with the info *available = true*.
How can this be achieved? Should I add this second rule in the *parse_item* function?

***EDIT***

My parse_item function looks like that

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    item = MyItem()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['name'] = sel.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
    return item
```

Comment: I've no experience with scrapy, but why dont't you just filter out the ```dontparse``` list afterwards using an ```if```-clause? Or you could use one of the parameters of the SgmlLinkExtractor-Class, see here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html(f.e. deny_domain etc.)  (BTW: You should expose more code, esp. the ```parse_item```-function, to get a detailed answer)

Answer (score 0):

[SgmlLinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor) accepts `process_value` callable:

> a function which receives each value extracted from the tag and
>   attributes scanned and can modify the value and return a new one, or
>   return `None` to ignore the link altogether. If not given,
>   `process_value` defaults to `lambda x: x`.

So something like this should help:

```
def process_value(value):
    unique_id = re.search(r"/item/(\d+)", value).group(1)
    if unique_id in already_crawled_site_ids:
        return None
    return value

rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/item/\d+']), 'parse_item', process_value=process_value)]
```